# Making sure Mouse is within coordinates of abstract shape

Tags: jquery, html

I'm unable to think of a process or method to do the following.  Any suggestions would be great.  The easiest way to explain what I'm trying to do would be similar to a map of US States.  A map of the states which highlight when moving over them.

I do not know how to create coordinates of a abstract object and have a mouseover event which activates (or triggers).

I've tried searching all over for something close, which I have found, but nothing that examples how the coordinates work.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple solutions are

- the good old [image maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)
- the [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format

Both allow you to define shapes on images in a HTML document and associate actions (usually links). SVG also allows the easy definition of styles changing when you hover a shape (see [tutorial](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs)).

Comment: Thank you.  It seems like SVG will be best for me.  But, both methods will work.

Comment: SVG is more used those days. Note that the free Inkscape software allows you to draw yourself the images. I like it because I can propose my customer to draw the images and define the hot shapes in the images. Note that you can also change the image from javascript (move shape, fill it with a gradient, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Also if you don't care about IE8 you can also overlay the map image with absolute positioned divs, and skew them into shape using  [Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform)

Comment: Although this will not be a good idea for this project I'm doing... This is very good to know!  Thanks for the info.